# scala.util.Try recursive function throws compilation error

Tags: scala

Given the following recursive function that returns Try[Int], I get a compilation error saying

`type mismatch; found : scala.util.Try[Int] required: Int`

But the function returns `Try[Int]`, what is wrong? I need the function to throw an error if Try results in Failure.

```
   def getInt(i: Int): Try[Int] = Try {
          if (i == 0)
              i
          else {
              val j = i - 1
              getInt(j)   // <-- error is thrown in this line
          }
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a Try inside a Try now.

Try (hah!) this:

```
def getInt(i: Int): Try[Int] = 
      if (i == 0)
          Success(0)
      else
          getInt(i-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

method `getInt` return `Try[Int]` so you are writing it like this:

```
Try { if (i == 0) return integer else return Try[Int] }
```

To fix this you have to do it this way:

```
  def getInt(i: Int): Try[Int] = 
    if (i == 0)
      Success(i)
    else {
      val j = i - 1
      getInt(j)   // <-- error is thrown in this line
    }
```

as `Success` extends `Try` this will work